# WhatsApp Web Login – web.whatsapp.com Can i use to Make Voice calls?

Tags: web, whatsapp

Since i was searching for Whatsapp Web I found that this is the only place where i can ask my Question . Actually I Want to Use [Whatsapp web](https://www.rootupdate.com/whatsapp-web-login/) on my laptop and i want to use voice calls on that. Now my main Question is that this website says that you can also make calls and video calls using whatsapp web so is it possible to make video calls using Web whtsapp

Answer (score 1):

While WhatsApp has a desktop application in the form of WhatsApp web,
the feature of making video calls from the desktop is still missing.
All that the app can actually do is let you manipulate your WhatsApp
phone app, but making calls is only through the phone.

Nevertheless, there is a workaround, which is tricking the phone app to think
that your computer is an Android phone by using a device emulator.
There are several free Android emulators
that you can try to make WhatsApp video calls on desktop.

See these references:

- [**How to Make WhatsApp Video Calls on Desktop (2020)**](https://mobiletrans.wondershare.com/whatsapp/how-to-make-whatsapp-video-calls-on-desktop.html)
  A tutorial based on the
  [BlueStacks emulator](https://www.bluestacks.com/).
- [**Top 7 Free and Online Android Emulators for PC**](https://drfone.wondershare.com/mirror-emulator/free-and-online-android-emulators.html)

Answer (score 0):

WhatsApp Web is not a standalone messaging service. Instead, it simply synchronizes with your phone and displays all of your recent messages.

There are several limitations to [WhatsApp web](https://www.techworm.net/2018/12/whatsapp-web-use-pc.html) one of which is no audio, video call features.